# Opencart theme is showing error after install on localhost but working good on existing site?

Tags: php, opencart

I have installed a fresh Opencart file. Now I have used a theme which client has sent to me. When I installed the theme it showed an error as `Notice: Undefined variable: text_items_no in Opencart/catalog/view/theme/epura/template/module/cart.tpl on line 1 item.` 
Now I thought there might be an error with the theme but when I visited the site where the theme has been activated there was no error. So can someone tell me what I am missing here?

**NOTE**
I am using the same versionf Opencart which the theme has been activated in the live site and also on my localhost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, there is no error in your theme integration. You are missing a single variable to initiate via the controller of cart module that is text_items_no, probably used for showing the number of items in text version.

so in the catalog/controller/module/cart.php initiated this variable and the notice will be removed.

Thanks.